# In Windows 8.1 how can set my IE to older versions(Compatibility View)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, windows-8.1

In Windows 8.1 IE, I cannot find the dropdown which includes all versions of IE to set to an older version to see the result?

Comment: you mean compatibility view?

Comment: You can try "Compatibility View". But as far as I know IE doesn't have  a dropdown to roll back to older versions.

Comment: If you are doing this for development, that you want to see the result of your page in other versions of IE, then I am afraid it won't work. Compatibility View only aims to render old style content in the new browser, it does not really mimic the behavior of the old browsers completely.

Comment: Yes I need Compatibility View, but I cannot find it as my IE updated recently and changed everything

Comment: it is still under the view you get when you press **F12**

Comment: yes I click F12,but I cannot see dropdown for selecting IE version

Comment: inside F12 press CTRL+8 here you can select the emulated version.

Comment: @Mehrdad I posted it as answer so that you can mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The setting is still there. Run IE, open the tool with <kbd>F12</kbd> and here press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>8</kbd> to get to the [Options to change the compatibility options and change the emulated IE version](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dn255001%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).
You can find the list of browsers as User agent string
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are missing the little icon for your Compatibility View, alternatively look unter **Settings -> Compatibility View settings**:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For finding that you need to Click F12 then Ctrl+8
On the page you find List of different browsers as: User Agent String

[image]